# How to set a route to a controller and access it via a form?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to set a route to my "MessagesController" so that a i can access it from my form, How do i set a route to the controller and access it from  action form ?

> This is my Form code

```
<form   action="#" id="ajax-contact" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  {{csrf_field()}}
   <div class="input-field">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="nom" required 
  placeholder="Nom">
  </div>

  <div class="input-field">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required 
  placeholder="E-mail">
  </div>

  <div class="input-field">
  <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" required 
   placeholder="Message"></textarea>
   </div>

   <button class="btn" type="submit">Soumettre</button>
 </form>
```

What should i write inside my `web.php` to set a route so i can acces my `MessageController.php` what should i write inside the `action` attribute ?

Comment: give a name to your route in MessagesController and access it like {{ route('name') }}. Or you can use {{ url('path') }} to the path with points to that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay not sure what you want but here is the whole thing

REQUEST(FORM) => ROUTE => CONTROLLER => RESPONSE

So you want to go from FORM to Controller you have to :

> Create a controller (in App\Http\Controllers) and a method

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
  // This method will handle the form
  // $request is where the form data will be
  public function handleForm(Request $request){
    // this means dump all form values
    dd($request->all());
  }
}
```

> Create a route ( In simple words, this will link between FORM & Controller method ) in web.php

```
// The request need to be POST to /handle-data 
Route::post('handle-data','MyController@handleForm');
```

> finally this should be your form

```
<form   action="/handle-data" id="ajax-contact" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  {{csrf_field()}}
   <div class="input-field">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="nom" required 
  placeholder="Nom">
  </div>

  <div class="input-field">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required 
  placeholder="E-mail">
  </div>

  <div class="input-field">
  <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" required 
   placeholder="Message"></textarea>
   </div>

   <button class="btn" type="submit">Soumettre</button>
 </form>
```

> If you want to make this as an ajax call

```
$( "#ajax-contact" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).serializeArray();

    $.post('/handle-data', data ).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
});

if you want to test the ajax way, change the dd($request->all()); to return response()->json($request->all());
```

That should be it :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit routes inside web.php to point to `submit` method in `MessagesController`:

```php
Route::post('submit', 'MessagesController@submit')->name('submit');
```

then set form action to:

```html
<form action="{{ route('submit') }}" id="ajax-contact" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

You should POST from a form.

Comment: that didn't work ! what i am trying to do is to acces my MessageController when i submit a form ?

Comment: @MohamedMidou, please be nicer and familiarize yourself with the rules on how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: alright thanks a lot

Comment: What methods have you got in MessageController?

Comment: I want to access the store method

Comment: So use this route: `Route::post('submit', 'MessagesController@store')->name('submit');`

Comment: alright that will do the job thanks brother